# How to get current user role with spring security plugin?

Tags: grails, spring-security, authorization, role

I am using the spring-security-core plugin in my grails app. I need to know the current user's role in a controller action. How can I retrieve that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can inject `springSecurityService` into your controller:

`def springSecurityService`

and then in your action, call:

`def roles = springSecurityService.getPrincipal().getAuthorities()`

See the docs [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/index.html).

Comment: if I use the following code, how can I check if the value of role is 'ROLE_USER' or 'ROLE_ADMIN'??

Comment: for(def role in roles){
if(role.getAuthority() == "ROLE_ADMIN")
//do something
}

Answer (score 20):

From a controller you can use two methods the plugin adds to the metaclass, `getPrincipal` and  `isLoggedIn`:

```
def myAction = {
   if (loggedIn) {
      // will be a List of String
      def roleNames = principal.authorities*.authority
   }
}
```

If the action is secured you can skip the `loggedIn`/`isLoggedIn()` check.

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize those were added to the metaclass. Are there any disadvantages to using, say, `authenticatedUser` in a controller over injecting the `springSecurityService` plugin? Looking at the plugin code, they seem mostly identical.

Comment: No difference, it's just more convenient.

Comment: Can a user-specific variable (such as roleNames) be stored as a controller field? I suppose it is not safe to store any state in the controller, because it will be shared. Am I right? If so, is there any trick to avoid duplication of this code throughout all of the controller's actions?

Answer (score 4):

If you simply need to check to see if a user is in a specific role then use `SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted` which takes a single String as an argument which contains a comma-delimited list of roles.  It will return true if the current user belongs to all of them.  `SpringSecurityUtils` also has methods like `ifAnyGranted`, `ifNotGranted`, etc, so it should work for whatever it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

To get the user

```
    def springSecurityService
    def principal = springSecurityService.principal
    String username = principal.username
```

Answer (score 0):

SecurityContextHolder knows that:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `getAuthenticatedUser()` by itself. This method is automatically injected in every controller, and thus only available from controllers. You will have to use one of the other methods if you want to access the current logged in user from anywhere else.